# KnockoutJS, Checkbox list reflecting which groups my currently selected object belongs to?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, knockout.js

This is the first time I post a question here, please let me know if I need to improve it. (including the title)

I have in my model two types of objects, Device and Group. A Device can belong to a Group or not, and a Group can contain Devices or not.

What I would like to do is to have a selectlist on the left, showing a list of Device.Name. When the user selects one of them, the details of the selected Device shows in the middle of the screen, and then on the right-hand side, have a list of checkboxes, each checkbox representing a Group.

The problem is I cannot find a way to define the Checked bindings of my checkboxes. I have tried defining an observableArray of CheckedGroup{ Group, bool }, but could not get the bool value to update dynamically according to the currently selected device.

My viewmodel:

```
function Device(data) {
  this.DeviceId = ko.observable(data.DeviceId);
  this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
  this.Number = ko.observable(data.Number);
  this.IpAddress = ko.observable(data.IpAddress);
  this.Description = ko.observable(data.Description);
  this.Groups = ko.observableArray();
  this.Groups = $.map(data.Groups, function (grp, i) {
    return grp;
  });
}

function Group(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.GroupId = ko.observable(data.GroupId);
  self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
  self.Description = ko.observable(data.Description);
}

function DevicesViewModel() {
  // Data
  var self = this;
  self.devices = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.groups = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.currentdevice = ko.observable();

  $.getJSON(deviceapiuri, function (data) {
    var mappeddevices = $.map(data, function (dev, i) {
      return new Device(dev)
    });
    self.devices(mappeddevices);
  });

  $.getJSON(groupapiuri, function (data) {
    var mappedgroups = $.map(data, function (grp, i) {
      return new Group(grp)
    });
    self.groups(mappedgroups);
  });
}
```

My View :

```
// The device list on the left side
<select id="devicelist_input" size="2" data-bind="options: devices, optionsText: function (i) { return i.Name }, value: currentdevice"> </select>

//One of the input fields that are bound to my currentdevice - this correctly updates when selecting my device.
<input id="stbdescription_input" type="text" data-bind="value: currentdevice() && currentdevice().Description" />

//The list of checkboxes I an trying to bind - the list is populated correctly, but the boxes' Checked property won't update according to the currentdevice
<div id= "group_check_list_input" data-bind="foreach: groups">
  <input type="checkbox" class="groupcheckbox" data-bind="value: $data, Checked:$root.currentdevice() && $root.currentdevice().Groups" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite difficult to get the checkbox selecting. The key thing to doing this is you must be using the same object in both the DevicesViewModel.groups and Device.groups. It needs to be exactly the same object and not just an object with the same data.

You can do this by passing in the viewModel groups to the device constructor and then if the the groupId matches then you add the group to the device groups. I did this using the following code:

```
function Device (device, groups) {
    this.DeviceId = ko.observable(device.DeviceId);
    this.Name = ko.observable(device.Name);
    this.Number = ko.observable(device.Number);
    this.IpAddress = ko.observable(device.IpAddress);
    this.Description = ko.observable(device.Description);

    var mappedGroups = $.map(device.Groups, function (grp) {
        var group = ko.utils.arrayFilter(groups, function(group) 
        {
            return group.GroupId() == grp.GroupId;
        });
        return group[0];
    });

    this.Groups = ko.observableArray(mappedGroups);
};
```

Other problems with your code is you are using value binding for the checkbox when you need to use checkedValue and checked can be just be set to $parent.Groups if you are using a with for the currentdevice.

```
<select data-bind="options: devices, optionsText: 'Name', value: currentdevice, optionsCaption: 'Select a device'"></select>
<div data-bind="with: currentdevice">
    <label>DeviceId:</label>
    <span data-bind="text: DeviceId"></span>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
    <label>Number:</label>
    <span data-bind="text: Number"></span>
    <label>IpAddress:</label>
    <span data-bind="text: IpAddress"></span>
    <label>Description:</label>
    <span data-bind="text: Description"></span>
    <div data-bind="foreach: $root.groups">
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $parent.Groups, checkedValue: $data"/><span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle of it working:

http://jsfiddle.net/k4kAU/1/

Comment: Thanks, that seems to solve it.
the 'checked' binding is still somehow obscure to me...
Since I am not within a div where it would make sense to use "with: currentdevice", I was using 
    <div data-bind="foreach: $root.groups">
      <input type="checkbox"data-bind="checked:$root.currentdevice().Groups, checkedValue:$data" />
I would understand the $parent in your code would refer to the same as currentdevice() in my code, yet it does not work this way... do you know why ?

Comment: The binding above in your comment is correct. It's the data that's incorrect. You need to make sure that the objects in $root.currentdevice().Groups are equal to the equivalent object in $root.groups

Comment: The problem is you can't use $root.currentdevice().Groups because initially no current device is selected so you are trying to get the groups for undefined. I wrapped an if around it: http://jsfiddle.net/k4kAU/4/

Comment: Would it make my life easier to use something like
data-bind="with: '#myselect.selected'" instead ? If this is possible, where should I look for the correct syntax?

Comment: Yes it would make your life easier using with. syntax can be found here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html. It's really just with: $root.currentdevice